# How to call the controller variable in view file using joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am new in joomla, My code is like this

```
//on controller
function listing()
    {
            JRequest::setVar( 'view', 'hello' );
            JRequest::setVar('hidemainmenu', 0);
            parent::display();                  
    }
//on view.html.php
```

i want to fetch this 'hidemainmenu'
How can i fetch can anyone help??

Comment: sorry to take your time JRequest::getVar('hidemainmenu')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code above is that of your view.html.php file then you can pass the variable through to your template file by using a line like so:

```
$this->assignRef( 'hidemainmenu', $hidemainmenu);
```

Then in your tmpl/default.php file for example you can access this variable like so:

```
$this->hidemainmenu
```

Comment: I was in the middle of posting the same thing.

Comment: to get the $hidemainmenu in the first place, I recommend using this if need be. 

$hidemainmenu = JRequest::getVar('hidemainmenu');

Answer (score 0):

If the code is in the Controller : 
get the Variable in the view.html.php

as

```
$hidemainmenu = JRequest::getVar('hidemainmenu');
```

Try this in the view.html.php or default.php